# Remove global.less css from Reactjs project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I have using the **ant-table-extensions** for display the data in table . but I have facing some issues like **antd** automatically import some css and it is disturbing my design. How can remove it. Even I have written css code in my index.js

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}
```

What is the solution for removing the global.less css ?

Answer (score 1):

You can namespace the antd styles, I was using less in my case

I created namespaced.less file with
// this will namespace the antd class with `antdContainer`

```
.antdContainer {
    @import '~antd/dist/antd.less';
}
```

import these styles in the app

```
import '../styles/namespaced.less';
```

Then when using antd components, wrap the components with

```
   <div className=" antdContainer">
   </div>
```

Hope it gives you some ideas to solve the problem